# Simple OCR for iPhone

Tags: ocr, iphone-app

I'm looking for a very simple app where I point the camera to a text, like a url in a browser, "click" the screen, and the OCR'ed text goes to my copy/paste...

So far, all apps needs me to take a picture, mark the text on the photo, submit, and on and on...

Is there a more direct one?